# Class "amsproc": how to add a dedication line between the article title, name and the abstract?

Tags: amsproc

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsproc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{color}
\parskip .2in

\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\bf Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}{\bf Claim}
\newtheorem*{claim 4.1}{\bf Claim 4.1}
\newtheorem*{claim 4.2}{\bf Claim 4.2}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{\bf Corollary}
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{\bf Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{\bf Remark}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{\bf Conjecture}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\bf Definition}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{\bf Fact}
\newtheorem{construction}[theorem]{\bf Construction}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{\bf Problem}


\def\G{{\Gamma}}

\def\C{{\mathcal C}}
\def\D{{\mathcal D}}
\def\B{{\mathcal B}}
\def\F{{\mathcal F}}
\def\N{{\mathcal N}}
\def\L{{\mathcal L}}
\def\H{{\mathcal H}}


\def\d{\delta}

\def\eps{\varepsilon}
\def\lf{\lfloor}
\def\rf{\rfloor}
\def\lc{\lceil}
\def\rc{\rceil}


\def\deg{{\rm deg}}
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\g{\gamma}
\def\P{\Phi}
\def\p{\varphi}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\t{\tau}
\def\fa{\mathfrak{a}}
\def\fb{\mathfrak{b}}
\def\fp{\mathfrak{p}}
\def\fq{\mathfrak{q}}
\def\bp{\mathbb{P}}
\def\exp{\mathbb{E}}
\def\Bar1{\overline}
\def\LAN{\rangle}
\def\RAN{\langle}

\def\Pf{{\bf Proof. }}
\def\ie{{\em i.e.}}
\def\eg{{\em e.g.}}

\def\e0{\eps_0}

\begin{document}
\title{{\bf My Title   }}


\author[A.S]{Amanda Stone}
\address{My Address}
\email{my email}


\date{\today}

\large

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

The above is the code. The format of the article is like this. The first line is the article title, then the name of the article, and then the abstract. I was intended to add the dedication line between the name and the abstract, with a small font probably. Could anyone help me with this please? Your time and attention is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Use `\dedicatory{My dedication}` before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this.  What I mainly did was move `\maketitle` before the `abstract` environment.  In that way, I could insert the dedication prior to the `abstract` while letting it remain after the `\maketitle`.  I set the dedication in its own group, centered, at a reduced font size.

EDITED to convert `\bf` and `\em` to modern LaTeX equivalents.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsproc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{color}
\parskip .2in

\newtheorem{theorem}{\textbf{Theorem}}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\textbf{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{claim}{\textbf{Claim}}
\newtheorem*{claim 4.1}{\textbf{Claim 4.1}}
\newtheorem*{claim 4.2}{\textbf{Claim 4.2}}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{\textbf{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{\textbf{Proposition}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{\textbf{Remark}}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{\textbf{Conjecture}}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\textbf{Definition}}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{\textbf{Fact}}
\newtheorem{construction}[theorem]{\textbf{Construction}}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{\textbf{Problem}}


\def\G{{\Gamma}}

\def\C{{\mathcal C}}
\def\D{{\mathcal D}}
\def\B{{\mathcal B}}
\def\F{{\mathcal F}}
\def\N{{\mathcal N}}
\def\L{{\mathcal L}}
\def\H{{\mathcal H}}


\def\d{\delta}

\def\eps{\varepsilon}
\def\lf{\lfloor}
\def\rf{\rfloor}
\def\lc{\lceil}
\def\rc{\rceil}


\def\deg{{\rm deg}}
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\g{\gamma}
\def\P{\Phi}
\def\p{\varphi}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\t{\tau}
\def\fa{\mathfrak{a}}
\def\fb{\mathfrak{b}}
\def\fp{\mathfrak{p}}
\def\fq{\mathfrak{q}}
\def\bp{\mathbb{P}}
\def\exp{\mathbb{E}}
\def\Bar1{\overline}
\def\LAN{\rangle}
\def\RAN{\langle}

\def\Pf{\textbf{Proof.}}
\def\ie{\emph{i.e.}}
\def\eg{\emph{e.g.}}

\def\e0{\eps_0}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{My Title}}


\author[A.S]{Amanda Stone}
\address{My Address}
\email{my email}


\date{\today}

\large

\maketitle

{\centering\footnotesize This is my dedication.\par}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}



\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the command `\dedicatory`. This is the way how the designers of the `amsproc` class want you to do it.

```
\dedicatory{To all those who helped me.}
...
\maketitle
```

By the way: Please don't use `\bf`, neither in the title (the class will take care of boldfacing the title itself), nor anywhere else in the article, since this command is deprecated since decades (use `{\bfseries My bold text.}` or `\textbf{My bold text.}` instead).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsproc}
\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author[A.S]{Amanda Stone}
\address{My Address}
\email{my email}
\date{\today}
\dedicatory{To all those who helped me.} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{abstract}
  The abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
My great paper.
\end{document}
```